# In Angular9, generating a help link to a different site based on current route

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add a link to the navbar of our Angular9 project that links to our support site based on the route (which can contain parameters in which case we want to replace that with 'id'). So if the route is `/superhero/{idParameter}` it would generate a link in the navbar for the help page at `www.oursupportpage.com/superhero-id`. If the route is `/superhero/admin/edit/{idParameter}` it would generate a link to `www.oursupportpage.com/superhero-admin-edit-id`.

I technically have it working via traversing the tree on the router at `router.routerState.snapshot._root`. This results in compilation errors, but it actually works on the site.

I am trying to come up with a better way of doing it, but haven't been successful so far. I feel like I am probably missing some easy solution of doing this fully automated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a child component to your navbar component (or whatever parent component is appropriate), that updates a link based on route events.

Here is a simple component which would display a dynamic link:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-support-link',
  template: '<a [href]="link?.link" target="_blank">{{ link?.text }}</a>'
})
export class SupportLinkComponent implements OnInit {

  link: any;

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    // set up subscription to router events
    this.router.events
      // filter on NavigationEnd to avoid firing more than once
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(url => {
        // update the link object for rendering
        this.link = {
          url: `www.oursupportpage.com/${url.split('/').join('-')}`,
          text: `support page`   // whatever you want to show here
        };
      });

  }

}
```

The key to this approach is the `this.router.events` Observable providing a stream of routing events that emit when you navigate around.